# Bash: ssh input to while loop

Tags: bash, loops, ssh, while-loop, aix

I'm trying to query the contents of a log file on a remote server, however, I can't seem to get it to work.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line; do
        echo "Do stuff to the file, line by line"
done < ( ssh -n user@server "cat /path/to/file" )
```

I get a syntax error at the first parenthesis.  If I remove the parenthesis, I get a syntax error at the "-n" flag.

Everything works properly from the shell, so I'm assuming there is some behavior here that I'm not understanding correctly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need another `<` for the process substitution.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line; do
        echo "Do stuff to the file, line by line"
done < <( ssh -n user@server "cat /path/to/file" )
```

The first `<` specifies the input redirection. The `<(...)` construct is the process substitution, which is similar to command substitution, but treated the output of the enclosed command as a file, rather than a string.